# Adicionar DIV removida em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Elaborei a seguinte condição:

jQuery:

```
$( "#selectOption" ).click(function() {
    var option = $( "#selectOption option:selected" ).val();
    if(option!='escolha'){
        if(option==2){
            $( "#atendimento_a" ).remove(); 
            $( "#locais_de_atendimento" ).remove(); 
            $( "#dias_de_atendimento" ).remove();
        }

        if(option==3){
            $( "#atendimento_a" ).remove(); 
            $( "#locais_de_atendimento" ).remove(); 
            $( "#dias_de_atendimento" ).remove();
            $( "#eu_adoro" ).remove();                  
        }
    } 
});
```

Form:

```
<select id="selectOption" name="selectOption">
    <option>escolha</option>
    <option value="1">destaque</option>
    <option value="2">mini</option>
    <option value="3">free</option>
</select>
```

Caso o retorno do select de opções for 2 ou 3, removo as divs em questão, como eu faço para ADICIONAR novamente as divs, caso a opção seja a opção 1? Sem que fique duplicado ou algo neste sentido??

Comment: Já testaste em vêz de `.remove()` usar `.hide()` e `.show()`?

Comment: Se precisa alternar, talvez seja melhor só esconder em vez de remover.

Comment: É uma opção! Vou testar! :)

Comment: Justo, resolveu meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: @AndréBaill ótimo. Juntei uma resposta com o código mais comprimido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que podias comprimir o código e usar algo assim, só com JavaScript nativo:

```
var elementos = ["atendimento_a", "locais_de_atendimento", "dias_de_atendimento", "eu_adoro"].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));
document.getElementById("selectOption").addEventListener('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    elementos.forEach(function(el) {
        if (el.id == 'eu_adoro') el.style.display = value == '3' ? 'none' : 'bloxk';
        else el.style.display = value == '1' ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Leghjpq/1

Ou então usando jQuery, ondeem regra geral usa-se `.hide()` e `.show()` em vêz de `.remove()`:

```
$("#selectOption").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $("#atendimento_a").toggle(value == '1');
    $("#locais_de_atendimento").toggle(value == '1');
    $("#dias_de_atendimento").toggle(value == '1');
    $("#eu_adoro").toggle(value == '1' || value == '2');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9Leghjpq/2

Answer (score 1):

Deixo aqui a resposta, conforme comentada pelo pessoal, caso alguém precise!

```
<select id="selectOption" name="selectOption">
    <option>escolha</option>
    <option value="1">destaque</option>
    <option value="2">mini</option>
    <option value="3">free</option>
</select>


$( "#selectOption" ).click(function() {
    var option = $( "#selectOption option:selected" ).val();
    if(option!='escolha'){

        if(option==1){
            $( "#atendimento_a" ).show();   
            $( "#locais_de_atendimento" ).show();   
            $( "#dias_de_atendimento" ).show();
            $( "#eu_adoro" ).show();                    
        }

        if(option==2){
            $( "#atendimento_a" ).hide();   
            $( "#locais_de_atendimento" ).hide();   
            $( "#dias_de_atendimento" ).hide();
        }

        if(option==3){
            $( "#atendimento_a" ).hide();   
            $( "#locais_de_atendimento" ).hide();   
            $( "#dias_de_atendimento" ).hide();
            $( "#eu_adoro" ).hide();                    
        }
    } 
});
```